# Inputting a string

Tags: c++

i want to store a string entered by the user including the space characters into the following array

```
char array[100];
```

how can i do it.

Comment: And what if the user enters 101 characters?

Comment: then ignore characters 101 and beyond. what's the problem?

Comment: @San Jacinto: Well, it *is* a big problem in practice, and responsible for many security holes in modern software. BTW, what happens if the user enters **100** characters?

Comment: @San Jacinto: You mentioned one problem yourself, "then ignore characters 101 and beyond."  Another is if you try to write 101 characters in to a 100-character array, you will (hopefully) blow up.

Comment: I'm still not getting the problem. As input enters your stream, you process it. Once you read as much as you want to read, IGNORE IT UNTIL YOU CAN PROCESS MORE. NEVER READ MORE THAN YOU CAN PROCESS SAFELY. This is the entire reason flow control was invented. The only time this is an issue is when you can't fix the code underneath that has the hole. At that point, there's nothing you can do about it and it is completely different than the question being asked. So again, what is the problem?

Comment: @John Dibling at some point, you need to give scope to the problem. You can either duck your head in the sand and pretend you don't have undefined behavior at characters 101+ (which is a problem, we agree), or you can ignore everything after character 100 (index 99) and determine if it's valid input. If not, you ignore all of it. This is how communications protocols work at their core.

Comment: Or you can accept input of arbitrary length.  Or you can handle errors more gracefully than just "ignoring" input.

Comment: @John Dibling obviously you want to accept input of arbitrary length, but, at some point your buffer just can't handle any more. For instance, the buffers on my 8051 aren't that large! What then? Perhaps I spoke too bluntly to be clear: just because your program ignores the rest of the input you cannot handle doesn't mean you don't inform the input source, clear your buffer, and start over with the current packet...

Comment: ...I'm otherwise not understanding why this is such an issue for you. At some point there just is no way to handle as much input as is available. Eventually, you punt. You tell the sender: "stop. start over here. I'm ignoring everything you send until you do this."

Comment: @San Jacinto: The problem is that programmers must check explicitly. In theory this shouldn't be a problem, of course, but in practice it is - otherwise we wouldn't have so many buffer overflow vulnerabilities. So I agree with John and Rudolph that we should discourage techniques that require manual checking.

Comment: @sbi that's fair enough, but somewhere along the line you MUST check. You can bury the logic in a class, or rely on someone else's class to do it, but eventually someone has to check that the buffer hasn't been overrun. Could you suggest another method to me? I'm willing to learn something.

Comment: @San Jacinto: `std::string line; std::getline(std::cin,line);` is an easy way to input a line from a stream with the string expanding automatically. The logic is buried in the standard library and that's tested by thousands, if not millions, of users. Less error-prone than doing it yourself.

Comment: @sbi making my point for me. Your method isn't the safest either. A user can enter as many characters as he wishes before the input is processed. In the work I usually do, this is worse than allowing potential for a buffer overflow (assuming you just forgot to check it, rather than intentionally leaving it out)..

Comment: @sbi ..I usually do input on one thread with a smaller buffer that feeds a larger buffer on a second thread, where I do the processing. It is this second buffer that is dynamically expanding, but here I have control of what goes on the 2nd buffer altogether. I do this quite frequently on MCU's that use serial comms to form a large network. If you don't obey the protocol, then you don't get serviced. But that is overkill, much like your method is overkill for small things. I assume the OP knows what they want to do better than I.

Comment: @San Jacinto: The OP doesn't even know what `std::cin.getline(array,100);` means. At this level of knowledge, `std::getline` is the best you can make use of. When you need to implement complicated protocols, more sophisticated methods might be necessary, but then more sophisticated knowledge is also necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to get the user-entered string to a string object, then convert it to whatever you need:

```
string c;
getline(cin, c);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cin.getline(array, 100, '\n');
```

Comment: @Zia ur Rahman: Stackoverflow can give you a hint into the right direction, but we cannot teach you the language. You won't have a chance to learn C++ without having a textbook to your aid to explain the things pointed out here. (BTW: I'd strongly suggest you abandon the idea of using character arrays. Use strings instead as shown in frbry's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111292/2111339#2111339)

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for getline can be found here: http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/